# Enable Presentation Mode permanently on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, power-management, iot

I want to enable the presentation mode forever on my Windows 10 device. When I turn it on, it again turns off after reboot or sign out. I have also tried to set the values through registry, but seems not to be working.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MobilePC\AdaptableSettings\SkipBatteryCheck > 1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MobilePC\MobilityCenter\RunOnDesktop > 1

The main reason why I want to enable it is, it's an unattended PC and I have tried all power settings to turn the sleep off. But after some time it goes to sleep mode.

Comment: So, from what I understand, you don't need to enable windows presentation mode, you need to prevent the PC from sleeping right?

Comment: Yes. Since I tried all other option that I know and those are not working. But this presentation mode works well unless the device is rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable presentation mode forever, I suggest you create a startup script to invoke it.

To control the presentation settings, you can call the executable directly, followed by the arguments. 
Example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\PresentationSettings.exe /start
```

or, to stop:

```
C:\Windows\System32\PresentationSettings.exe /start
```

If the first line is scheduled to run at boottime then Presentation mode will always be activated.

Comment: Can you confirm that this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your main goal from what your question shows, is to prevent your system from switching off the screen or hibernating or anything like that. 
In which case, if you have tried disabling all the energy saving features that you know of, and the PC is still hibernating, then I suggest you use Caffeine. 
It costs nothing and it's adware free.

Quote:

> Caffeine works in a rather simple way to try and prevent your computer
>   going into standby, the screen from shutting off or even the
>   screensaver kicking in. This is to simulate a key press once every 59
>   seconds so Windows is fooled into thinking you’re using your computer
>   when in fact, you aren’t.

Get it from zhornsoftware, and the link below: 
zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/index.html#download

Comment: Yes, I have replicated same thing in my application (which runs always on device) what Caffeine does, triggering F15 key press event every 50 seconds. Will have to wait till 24 hours to make sure that it's working. Isn't there a way to enable the presentation mode forever?